# How to start second activity from header of NavigationView by ImageButton?

Tags: android, onclick, header, imagebutton, navigationview

I couldnt to start second activity throwgh onClick. I create ImageButton in the header of NavigationView. 
This is part of the code. I commented where the error occurred. Please help me.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

ImageButton ib;
NavigationView navigationView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    ib = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) 
    findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", 
        Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, 
R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) 
    findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    ib.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
     public void onClick(View v) {
      switch (v.getId()){
       case R.id.imageButton:
        Intent loginActivity=new 
        Intent(this,LoginActivity.class);//here shows the error on LoginActivity.class
                    startActivity(loginActivity);
            }
    }});}
```

Comment: I think you are passing wrong context. try this :
Intent loginActivity=new   Intent(getContext(),LoginActivity.class);

Comment: What is the error message, if any?

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                Process: com.example.john.myapp, PID: 12345
                                                                                java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.......

Comment: this is in LogCat

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
 Intent loginActivity=new 
    Intent(this,LoginActivity.class);/
```

To

```
 Intent loginActivity=new 
    Intent(MainActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
```

Also change

```
ib = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
```

To

```
ib = (ImageButton)toolbar.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
```

Comment: unhelpfully. Has displayed: Unfortunately, myapp has stopped

Comment: And it didn't help.

Comment: @Iwantask post your logcate